# Generalization of Penney's game (Penney's paradox)

Tags: game-theory

The standard [Penney's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game) is played by two players.  Player $A$ chooses a sequence of $k>2$ bits and $B$ (seeing $A$'s selection) chooses a different sequence of $k$ bits.  A fair coin is flipped repeatedly; whichever player's sequence appears *first* in the (long) sequence of random coin flips is the winner.

Paradoxically, no matter what sequence $A$ chooses, $B$ can choose a different sequence that is more likely to appear before $A$'s.  For instance, for $k=3$, if $A$ chooses $HHH$, then $B$ should choose $THH$.  In $1/8$ games, the $HHH$ will appear as the first three coin tosses and $A$ will win; in *all other games* $B$ will win because before $HHH$ can appear, $B$'s sequence $THH$ *must* appear.  If instead $A$ chose $THH$, then $B$ should choose $TTH$, which is more likely to appear first.  Here are some simulations illustrating the effect:

- $HHH\underline{TTH}TTTTHHTTT$:  B wins
- $H\underline{TTH}TTHTHHTHHTT$:  B wins
- $H\underline{TTH}THHHHHHTHTT$:  B wins
- $H\underline{TTH}THHTTHTHHHT$:  B wins
- $HHHTT\underline{TTH}THHTHTH$:  B wins
- $TTTTTT\underline{THH}THHTTH$:  A wins
- $\underline{TTH}TTTHTHTHHHTH$:  B wins
- $HH\underline{TTH}TTTTTHHTTT$:  B wins
- $HHHHHHH\underline{THH}TTHHT$:  A wins
- $\underline{TTH}TTTHHHHTHTHT$:  B wins
- $\underline{THH}HTHTTTTHTHHT$:  A wins
- $TH\underline{THH}TTTHTTHTTH$:  A wins

And so on.  Thus the available sequences exhibit non-transitive dominance:  $\alpha_1 > \alpha_2 > \ldots > \alpha_1$, where the $\alpha_i$ are distinct $k$-bit sequences and "$>$" means "is more likely to appear first in a sequence randomly generated by a fair coin."

In short, if $B$ plays optimally, he is guaranteed (in probability) to win most the games.

Let's call that traditional Penney game a *one-level* game, because only one sequence match is needed for termination.

Consider a *two-level* generalization, in which $A$ first chooses *two* different $k$-bit sequences and $B$ (seeing $A$'s choices) chooses two different sequences (not already chosen by $A$).  The game proceeds as before, with random coin flips, but now the winner is the first to have *both* his chosen sequences appear, in either order and at any separation.  (Allow overlaps of sequences.)

***Question***

Is there an optimal strategy for $B$ such that he is guaranteed (in probability) to win most two-level Penney games?

Comment: My brute-force simulation for k=3 does not find that Bob can beat Alice's pair THH, HHT. None of his strategies beat 50% with statistical significance in a million trials. (It is possible he has a slight edge but more trials are needed to detect it.)

Comment: @usul:  Please check your code and assumptions.  As the table (Analysis of the three-bit game) in the linked wikipedia page states, the odds in favor of $TTH$ over $THH$ are 2:1.  (I'll run my own simulations to confirm too.) . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game

Comment: @usul:  My computer simulations confirm the 2:1 odds ratio described in the wikipedia page.  Please check that page and your code.  Also, on that page there is a helpful "intuitive" explanation why the non-transitive dominance woks.

Comment: oops, I was unclear. I refer not to the original problem but to your question about two-level generalization. When I simulate Alice's choice of the two sequences (THH, HHT), I cannot find any pair of length-3 sequences $(x,y)$ for Bob such that, with probability noticeably over 0.5, both $x$ and $y$ appear as subsequences prior to both TTH and HHT.

Comment: In the two-level game winning is the FIRST  to get BOTH his sequences.  They need not both be before both the opponent’s sequences.  If A then B then A then B... A wins.  Clear?

Comment: Clear and consistent with my current code. Again my comment was not clear enough! :) (I had tried to edit it, but passed the 5 minute window)

Comment: The intransitivity in the one-level game only shows up for $k\ge3$. Perhaps the calculations of @usul are telling us that intransitivity in the two-level game doesn't show up at $k=3$, but that might just mean we need to look at some larger $k$ to find it.

Comment: Excellent point.  Makes sense.  I would have thought that the largest odds ratio would show up, though.  I will try A:  HHH and TTT, B:  HTT and THH.

Comment: Seems there are some variations of this problem in the $n$-level game. (A and B each pick $n$ distinct $k$ bit sequences, all $2n$ sequences distinct.) The most natural definition of a win for B is the last of the $2n$ sequences to appear belongs to A, but even then there are ${2n-1 \choose n}$ possibilities that the choices of A and B may appear in. Perhaps some variations could fix some subset of these possibilities as winning for B.

Comment: Suppose we identify the set of $k$-bit sequences with $\{0,...,2^k-1\}$ in the natural way. It seems there is a function from the set of infinite binary strings with starting points and in which every $k$-bit sequence appears at least once to the symmetric group on $\{0,...,2^k-1\}$, and it naturally gives rise to a probability distribution on such a set of permutations. Perhaps the original question could be asked for any probability distribution?

Comment: For $k=4$, suppose Alice plays (HTTT, TTTH). My simulations say that if Bob is allowed to play (HHTT. TTTH), where he's copied one of Alice's pair, then he can win 58% of the time. But if this is disallowed as per the rules, then his best strategy seems to be (HHHT, THHH) resulting in (apparently) a tie.

Comment: It is not permissible for Bob to choose the *same* sequence as Alice (TTTH); we cannot allow ties.

Comment: That is to say: as far as I can tell, if Alice plays (HTTT, TTTH), then Bob's best legal response is (HHHT, THHH), resulting in an apparent 50% win rate. If this is correct, then it shows Bob does not have a winning strategy for k=4.

Comment: @usul: The apparent tie is a tie by symmetry; Bob's sequences are the complements of Alice's sequences. Bob can always tie in this way unless Alice chooses two complementary sequences. An interesting question might be whether Alice can choose complementary sequences such that Bob can't even tie.